# Is there a way to show just the meta text of every post through code?

Tags: tumblr, meta-tags

For some reason the Tumblr variable {MetaDescription} besides the text of a post include also the title.

For example:

- Title: How to eat
- Text: I will explain you in this post how...

How is inside Tumblr custom tool:

```
meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}"
```

This is how shows the meta description online in that post:

```
meta name="description" content="How to eat I will explain you in this post how..."
```

This is a problem for SEO. There's any way to show **just the text** of every post changing/adding something in the code related to the meta name="description"?

Comment: What is your exact problem? Please add additional details to your question. You can doing it by clicking the edit link underneath your question.

Comment: You can't edit `{MetaDescription}` however you can use any of the variable blocks to create your own. `{block:Text}{Title}{/block:Text}` etc.

Comment: @mikedidthis I though about it. But the only way on that idea is this one: {block:Text}{Body}{/block:Text} and of course you don't want all the body content of a post in the description. You know a way to limit that to 160 characters? maybe using HTML?

Comment: There isn't a Tumblr template to truncate text. I would imagine if the description is over the limit a search engine would truncate it anyway?

Comment: @mikedidthis Not necessarily, search engines can scan the all post, but they take just meta description you set into the SERP. That's why is so important. About your suggestion of fix: doesn't work, looks like Tumblr don't let you use other variable. Any other idea?